# Google OAuth: custom scheme for desktop app

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate a desktop application with OAuth. I already asked a question, but I deleted it as I discovered that the method was obsolete (integrated web view).

The idea is to open the browser and then have the page call back my application with a custom:// URI scheme.

Of course it doesn't work, Google asks that the scheme contains a dot (like com.org.myapp), but the native app can only have a fmp:// uri scheme, which I can't change.

The documentation doesn't mention anything, and I can't create a local temporary server.

1- Can I use the fmp:// scheme as a callback in *any* way?
2- If not, is it possible to redirect the call to another centralised web server? Everything I try generates a 400 error on the google page, saying "redirect_uri_mismatch" or similar stuff.

Comment: Just adding that I solved the problem in another way, the callback is an URL to a public server, which at every request creates a record in our database containing the authentication code. Still it would be nice to use these URLs.

Comment: What is the OS where custom url can't have dot? please also see [this question and my answer]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264213/oauth2-openid-connect-javascript-electron-desktop-application/45278030?

Comment: It's google that refuses the scheme without the dot, as stated in the documentation

Comment: It would be helpful to make your case to me so if there is a good reason, we can make that change. I'm trying to understand your use case. "Google refuses to do" does not help.

Comment: "we can make that change"..? Do you actually work for Google? Anyway the URL scheme exists because of iOS apps as far as I see, they can register custom URL schemes. My case is that a native application opens the browser, which performs the login, and as a redirect it calls a custom url that passes the app the token. This way I don't have to install an intermediate server that accepts the request and passes the state to the app internally. Please tell me if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: The important point is that I can't change the custom app scheme and I can't register a new, it's a RAD database tool with limited OS integration capabilities (FileMaker).

Comment: Yes, I do work for Google. For now the easiest may be for you to redirect the code to a server and then do the redirect on your own. When you create the clientid at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient  select Application type to be "Web Application".  You can then redirect the code to your custom scheme. This present a new issue. In order to be a Web application, you need to use a secret to exchange the code into refresh token.  Depending on who this tool is for and who all will be using it, you may have to put the secret in the client or there are other options.

Comment: ...and that's exactly what I'm doing right now. I am actually already using the secret to identify keys that are written in the database by the web server. The client application then searches for the new key during the login procedure every second. Overall it's very fast, so this is my definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, the only solution is to create an intermediate web server that serves a page which then opens the URL. OR creates a record in the database with the authentication code.